# D/EGL_emulation time messages in Flutter

Tags: flutter, debugging, console, android-emulator, emulation

I receive multiple messages of the following kind when I do anything in Android emulator in the flutter app

```
D/EGL_emulation(6380): app_time_stats: avg=1505.58ms min=1505.58ms max=1505.58ms count=1
```

What is it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: to me it's pretty clear he asks what that message means and none of the answer answer that question, instead explain how to hide it.. :)

Answer (score 18):

For **Visual Studio Code Users**:

You can always filter messages by using the **Filter input** on the *top right corner*.

For this particular case, you can hide those messages by applying this filter: **!D/EGL**

**BEFORE**: Without filtering:

[image: BEFORE: Without filtering]

**AFTER**: With filtering:
[image]

Comment: do you have a more permanent solution?

Answer (score 8):

- Right click on `D/EGL_emulation ...`
- Click "Fold Lines Like This"
- Edit the filter that's just been added to only contain `D/EGL_emulation`.
- All these lines will be removed from the RUN console window now

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 6):

In **Terminal (Mac/ Linux):**

If you run the flutter command inside terminal, to filter those messages
simply just run this command to filter

```
flutter run | grep -v "D/EGL_emulation"
```

or

```
flutter run | grep -v "app_time_stats"
```

Comment: Best solution for terminal users I've found.

Comment: in case someone's using powershell, try using this: `flutter run 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern "EGL_emulation"  -NotMatch`

Comment: Hey thankyouuu easiest solution for vscode user! and this command filter so portable. If i need it i can just remove the grep.

Answer (score 4):

1.) Right click on "D/EGL_emulation" click **fold line like this**

[image: 1)]

2.) This tab will popup
[image]

3.) Edit the currently selected line and just left "D/EGL_emulation:" then press ok.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was used an emulator with android S, my friend recommended me to use android R and the log its over. try it!

Comment: Good suggestion, worked for me! Downgraded api on the emulator from 13 to 11 and it helped to speed things up

Answer (score 1):

### In case you are using VS Code and Powershell instead of CMD:

here's what I've been using now, which also mutes the info on text input fields:

```
flutter run 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern "EGL_emulation", "D/InputMethodManager", "D/InsetsController", "W/RemoteInputConnectionImpl", "I/TextInputPlugin"  -NotMatch
```

you can add all other messages that occour too with the pattern

Answer (score 0):

This is an Android Studio emulator message, and in this case, is a "Debug" message. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71209827/16593914) to filter out the Debug messages from either Android Studio or VS Code, while keeping the Warnings and Errors.

Answer (score -1):

1.right click on "D/EGL_emulation( 6380): app_time_stats"
2.fole lines like this

it work for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually, this works great. Thanks. I clicked on "Fold Lines Like This", then edited the filter to just contain `D/EGL_emulation`. PERFECT. Thank you